# SSIS Package connection manager password not seen in SSMS Catalog configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a Connection Manager that is connecting to a SQL Server database using SQL credentials, i.e., not Windows Authentication. **Save my password** is checked. It's been deployed to a SQL Server as a job and is running fine. Now, we have a 3rd party vendor who is trying to interface with our SQL jobs. When we open the configuration window in SSMS's SSIS Catalog and go to this connection manager, the password is empty. Our vendor needs to grab the password. Does anyone know why it's empty, or alternatively, where our vendor can get the password from?

Comment: By you giving it to them. SSIS won't expose the passwords to you; that would be a huge security risk. If *you* don't know what the password is you don't know it for a reason.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But the password has to be stored somewhere, since the package does run. Perhaps it's encrypted?

Comment: Actually password is there, but SSIS hide it when you open SSMS. reason should be because of security. if you want third party to integrate with SQL jobs, better just provide password to them

Comment: Have you tried opening your project in code view and looking for it?